# Lax co/limit as evaluation on terminal/initial

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, 2-categories

A quick question about lax co/limits.

Strictly, when $F : J\to \bf A$ is a diagram and $J$ has an initial object $\varnothing$, then $\varprojlim F \cong F(\varnothing)$; dually, if $\cal J$ has a terminal object, then $\varinjlim F\cong F(*)$.

> If $F$ is a diagram between 2-categories (same notation), and $J$ has a lax initial, lax terminal object, is a similar statement true for lax co/limits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  If $\mathcal{J}$ is the interval category (two objects and one nonidentity morphism between them), which certainly has an initial and a terminal object, then the lax limits and colimits of such a diagram are comma objects of the morphism that determines its image, neither of which is usually equivalent to its domain or codomain.

Comment: I agreed the first time I read this, but then I thought: isn't the comma object the lax limit of a cospan?

Comment: No, the lax limit of a cospan is different from the comma object; it involves two nonidentity 2-cells, whereas the comma object involves only one.

Comment: Ah, the nLab page solved the terminology issue that you raised (or that I misinterpreted until today). The lax co/limit of $f : X \to Y$, seen as a diagram $\Delta[1] \to\cal A$, is the comma of $f$ and the identity (which is the way I interpreted your answer at first sight). So, thanks again!